# Removeclass doesn't work for image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like your help please on this please.

I am not able to remove the active link from unselected image.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".Nav_thumb a").click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');     
        });
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="pageNav_thumb">
    <div class="Nav_thumb">  
        <a id="img1" href="javascript:();" onClick="ShowVideo(1); return false;"> 
            <img src="img/Press2.jpg" height="79" width="140" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="Nav_thumb">   
        <a id="img2" href="javascript:();" onClick="ShowVideo(2); return false;">
            <img src="img/Working2g.jpg" height="79" width="140" />
        </a>
    </div> 
    <div class="Nav_thumb">   
        <a id="img3" href="javascript:();" onClick="ShowVideo(3); return false;"> 
            <img src="img/Press2.jpg" height="79" width="140" />
        </a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pageNav_thumb {
    width: 850px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background:url(../img/foot_04.jpg) no-repeat;
    min-width:850px;
    height:210px;
}
.Nav_thumb {margin:30px 0 0 10px; float:left;}
.Nav_thumb  A { display:inline-block; border: 2px solid rgb(51,51,51);}
.Nav_thumb  A:hover { border: 2px solid red; }
.Nav_thumb A:active  { border: 2px solid red;}
.Nav_thumb A:focus {outline:0;}
```

Comment: um, why are you removing and adding on the same element!

Comment: Why are you doing `$(function(){` AND `$(document).ready(..`? Since they are both the same

Comment: `$(function() {})` is synonymous with `$(document).ready(function () {})`, there is no need to nest them.

Answer (score 2):

maybe like somethig like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvUvP/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Nav_thumb a").click(function() {
        $('.Nav_thumb a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 
});
```